# Diccionario xml serializer

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa en el cual me gustaría serializar mi diccionario en xml.
Y que al entrar en programa se lea de vuelta el archivo.

```
 Dictionary<string, int> CodigosTC = new Dictionary<string, int> {{ "USD", 318 }, { "JPY", 325 }, { "EUR", 333 }, { "CHF", 326 }, { "CAD", 328 }, { "XDR", 329 }, { "GBP", 330 }, { "MXN", 332}, {"SEK", 335},{"KRW",337},{"GTQ",338}, {"HNL", 339},{"NIO",340},{"DKK",342}, {"NOK", 343}, { "ARS", 344 }, { "COP", 345}, { "BRL", 346 }, { "DOP",3043}, { "HKD", 3052 }, { "TWD", 3053 },
                {"BOP",3054}, {"CLP",3055}, {"RUB",3056}, {"PEN",3057}, {"CNY",3364}, {"PLN",3430}, {"AUD",3433},{"LKR",20873}, {"BDT",21251}, {"TBH",21262}, {"IDR",21263}, {"AED",21264}, {"MAD",21265}, {"ILS",21266}, {"INR",21267},{"EGP",21268}, {"NZD",21269}, {"SGD",21270}, {"VND",21766}, {"ZAR",21881},{"JOD",22204}, {"MYR",25067},{"UYN",84857} };

            Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myText.txt");

            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, int>));
            xmlSer.Serialize(stream, CodigosTC);
            stream.Close();
```

Al probar el programa me da este error, el archivo txt se crea en la carpeta, pero el archivo txt queda en blanco

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'El tipo System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] no es compatible porque implementa IDictionary.'
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda o explicación.

Comment: No tiene sentido cargar un txt a diccionario solo para ahorrar código. Tendría sentido si fuese un archivo de configuración al cual se le desea hacer cambios luego de compilar.

Comment: tiene mucho sentido si lo que quieres es ahorrar ram y solo buscar lo que necesitas para aligerar el programa y su carga inicial, la respuesta seria leerlo y cargarlo con las funciones de leer archivos https://shorturl.at/rvI01

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Estimado @John, yo dije claramente "solo para ahorrar código" que era el sentido de su pregunta original antes que la editara. No obstante, para ahorrar ram tampoco tendría sentido.

Comment: si estas usando c# en sistemas embebidos (chip o pic) pues si es buena la idea.
si no, por el contrario lo estas usando en un pc con recursos mas de 4megas de ram pues no hay problema en usar el diccionario dentro del codigo, incluso es mas recomendable que el xml externo.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas en vez de usar stream para escribir que se puede y meter un serializer puedes usar XmlWriter que te permite crearlo a tu antojo como quieres el xml. Un ejemplo:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> CodigosTC = new Dictionary<string, int> {{ "USD", 318 }, { "JPY", 325 }, { "EUR", 333 }, { "CHF", 326 }, { "CAD", 328 }, { "XDR", 329 }, { "GBP", 330 }, { "MXN", 332}, {"SEK", 335},{"KRW",337},{"GTQ",338}, {"HNL", 339},{"NIO",340},{"DKK",342}, {"NOK", 343}, { "ARS", 344 }, { "COP", 345}, { "BRL", 346 }, { "DOP",3043}, { "HKD", 3052 }, { "TWD", 3053 },
            {"BOP",3054}, {"CLP",3055}, {"RUB",3056}, {"PEN",3057}, {"CNY",3364}, {"PLN",3430}, {"AUD",3433},{"LKR",20873}, {"BDT",21251}, {"TBH",21262}, {"IDR",21263}, {"AED",21264}, {"MAD",21265}, {"ILS",21266}, {"INR",21267},{"EGP",21268}, {"NZD",21269}, {"SGD",21270}, {"VND",21766}, {"ZAR",21881},{"JOD",22204}, {"MYR",25067},{"UYN",84857} };
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();//opcional pero recomendable para configurar como se comporta el xmlwriter
      settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myText.txt",settings);
     
        

        
        foreach (string key in CodigosTC.Keys)//bucle para coger cada dato
        {

         
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(key);//creamos un elemento que es igual a la clave
            xmlWriter.WriteValue(CodigosTC[key]);//metemos el valor del diccionario
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();//cerramos el elemento
          
         

        }
       
        xmlWriter.Close();
```

El resultado(no configure espacios, por eso sale así):

```
<USD>318</USD><JPY>325</JPY><EUR>333</EUR><CHF>326</CHF><CAD>328</CAD><XDR>329</XDR><GBP>330</GBP><MXN>332</MXN><SEK>335</SEK><KRW>337</KRW><GTQ>338</GTQ><HNL>339</HNL><NIO>340</NIO><DKK>342</DKK><NOK>343</NOK><ARS>344</ARS><COP>345</COP><BRL>346</BRL><DOP>3043</DOP><HKD>3052</HKD><TWD>3053</TWD><BOP>3054</BOP><CLP>3055</CLP><RUB>3056</RUB><PEN>3057</PEN><CNY>3364</CNY><PLN>3430</PLN><AUD>3433</AUD><LKR>20873</LKR><BDT>21251</BDT><TBH>21262</TBH><IDR>21263</IDR><AED>21264</AED><MAD>21265</MAD><ILS>21266</ILS><INR>21267</INR><EGP>21268</EGP><NZD>21269</NZD><SGD>21270</SGD><VND>21766</VND><ZAR>21881</ZAR><JOD>22204</JOD><MYR>25067</MYR><UYN>84857</UYN>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]